# Select multiple columns in sub query after where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to compare a one column value to multiple column values,
near where clause below is my issue, like i want to get the data of the user's co-departments 4(IT_Infrasec) & 10(finance), please teach me, it says that sub query should have only one column but i don't know how to solve it

```
SELECT * FROM 
                        ( 
                        SELECT
                        chronos.chronos_id AS id
                        , chronos.dept_id AS dept_id
                        , chronos.name AS user_name
                        , departments.name AS department_name
                        , forms.formName AS form_name
                        , chronos.request_date AS date_requested
                        , chronos.status AS STATUS
                        FROM employees 
                        INNER JOIN users ON employees.user_id = users.id 
                        INNER JOIN departments ON employees.dept_id = departments.id 
                        INNER JOIN chronos ON users.name = chronos.name 
                        INNER JOIN forms on chronos.request_type_id = forms.id 
                        UNION ALL 
                        SELECT
                         leaves.leave_id AS id
                        , leaves.dept_id AS dept_id
                          , leaves.name AS user_name
                          , departments.name AS department_name
                          , forms.formName AS form_name
                          , leaves.request_date AS date_requested
                          , leaves.status AS STATUS
                          FROM employees 
                          INNER JOIN users ON employees.user_id = users.id
                          INNER JOIN departments ON employees.dept_id = departments.id 
                          INNER JOIN leaves ON users.name = leaves.name 
                          INNER JOIN forms on leaves.forms_id = forms.id 
                         UNION ALL 
                         SELECT
                          time_reserve.time_id AS id
                          , time_reserve.dept_id AS dept_id
                          , time_reserve.name AS user_name
                          , departments.name AS department_name
                         , forms.formName AS form_name
                          , time_reserve.request_date AS date_requested
                          , time_reserve.status AS STATUS
                          FROM employees 
                          INNER JOIN users ON employees.user_id = users.id 
                          INNER JOIN departments ON employees.dept_id = departments.id 
                          INNER JOIN time_reserve ON users.name = time_reserve.name 
                          INNER JOIN forms ON time_reserve.forms_id = forms.id
                         UNION ALL 
                         SELECT
                          offset.off_id AS id
                          , offset.dept_id AS dept_id
                          , offset.name AS user_name
                          , departments.name AS department_name
                          , forms.formName AS form_name
                          , offset.request_date AS date_requested
                          , offset.status AS STATUS
                          FROM employees 
                          INNER JOIN users ON employees.user_id = users.id 
                          INNER JOIN departments ON employees.dept_id = departments.id 
                          INNER JOIN offset ON users.name = offset.name 
                          INNER JOIN forms ON offset.forms_id = forms.id
                        ) t   where dept_id in 
                          (SELECT IT_Infrasec,Finance,Management,Business FROM mobile_access
                          INNER JOIN users 
                          ON users.id = mobile_access.userID 
                          WHERE users.username = 'username' ) ORDER BY date_requested DESC;
```

Comment: From where you are getting these values - `IT_Infrasec,Finance,Management,Business`? Are they columns in any table?

Comment: yes these are the columns in my table and i want to compare their values in dept_id

Comment: Which table contains these columns?

Answer (score 0):

What mysql doesn like
is

```
where dept_id in 
              (SELECT IT_Infrasec,Finance,Management,Business FROM mobile_access
               INNER JOIN users 
               ON users.id = mobile_access.userID 
              WHERE users.username = 'username'
```

Your select returns 4 columns, but it is only allowed one column.

I don't know which of them has the wanted   dept_id, but you need to generate a query which returns only one column

Like

```
SELECT ID FROM mobile_access
```

Comment: the IT_Infrasec,Finance

Comment: @MaroonDre I don't understand you comment if all columns have data you can union them or you can make a CONCAT with a GROUP_CONCAT

Answer (score 0):

```
where dept_id in 
              (SELECT IT_Infrasec FROM mobile_access
               INNER JOIN users 
               ON users.id = mobile_access.userID 
              WHERE users.username = 'username')
```

Note: Only 1 column should be used in the sub-query of an IN clause.